# How display this only on Wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress

This code display on every page content of page id 2. How edit this code, to display content only on homepage?

```
<?php
$recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2");
while ($recent->have_posts()):
    $recent->the_post();
?>
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: can you please explain a little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Answer (score 1):

**As home page can be a static front page too, in that case is_home() fails so ..**

**A combination of [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) should be used.**

```
<?php 
 if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
    $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); 
    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php } else{ 

    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <?php endwhile; 
  }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
<?php 
 if(is_home()){
    $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); 
    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php } else{ 

    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <?php endwhile; 
  }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
$home_page_post_id = 2;
$home_page_post = get_post( $home_page_post_id, ARRAY_A );
$content_home = $home_page_post['post_content'];
echo $content_home;
?>
```

Look at the get_post function for more details on how it is working: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post